# How to re-open Room database upon new db file

Tags: android

I am copying a backup sqlite-file into the path `getDatabasePath(OfferingsDatabase.DB_NAME)` on the device. The copy process works totally fine.

**The big problem is: How do I tell Room that it should re-open the (new) database?** I am using a singelton to retrieve the Database instance:

```
public static OfferingsDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if(INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized (LOCK){
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), OfferingsDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                    .setJournalMode(JournalMode.TRUNCATE)
                    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_5_6)
                    .build();
        }
    }

    return INSTANCE;
}
```

To populate the view, I do:

```
private void setupViewModel() {
    OfferingsViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(OfferingsViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getOfferings().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), (List<OfferingEntity> offeringEntries) -> {
        mOfferingsAdapter = new OfferingsAdapter(getContext());
        mOfferingsAdapter.setOfferings(offeringEntries);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mOfferingsAdapter);
    });
}
```

Once this code is executed after the db copy process, I noticed that `offeringEntries` is empty even though the new db file has data. It seems that Room does not know how to re-connect. How can I trigger a re-connect?

Comment: After migration your table might be clear. Not expected but still

Comment: "How do I tell Room that it should re-open the (new) database?" -- [`close()` the database](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase#close()) before restoring the backup. Re-open it yourself the same way that you open it normally, with a `RoomDatabase.Builder`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks, I tried it but when `setupViewModel()` is called, `offeringsEntries` is still empty even though there should be data.

Comment: `getOfferings()` needs to return a fresh `LiveData` from the DAO. If `getOfferings()` has a cached `LiveData`, that would explain your symptoms.

Comment: It seems that it's a UI refresh issue. The RecyclerView holding the items resides in a fragment in a TabLayout. Once I first return to RecyclerView, no items are refreshed but once I switch tabs and go back to the RecyclerView tab, the fresh data is there. So it seems the db has been imported correctly but not sure how I can update the RecyclerView directly without having to switch tabs.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Sorry, I have one more question regarding your comment: How do you re-open the DB with `RoomDatabase.Builder` if that's a singelton?

Comment: Have a `static` method that closes the database and nulls out `INSTANCE`. Your next `getInstance()` call will open the database; make sure that call is after the restore is complete.

Comment: I did that but it seems that this change has no effect. The reason is, after restore I use `OfferingsViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(OfferingsViewModel.class)` to re-populate my view. When I debug into it, I notice that this method does not call `getInstance()` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CommonsWare's comment, it works now. My previous getOfferings() was:

```
public LiveData<List<OfferingEntity>> getOfferings(){
    return mOfferings;
}
```

where mOfferings was the LiveData created in the constructor. But the constructor was never called. Instead, I must call:

```
public LiveData<List<OfferingEntity>> getOfferings(){
    return mOfferingsRepository.getAllOfferings();
}
```

This way I retrieve fresh LiveData.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from caching the `LiveData` in `mOfferings`. However, you need to reset that cache after restoring the database.